# Django Form doesn't show the initial value

Tags: python, django

I don't know if i'm doing something wrong but even when i set a initial value in a django form, that value doesn't show in the form.

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    content = forms.CharField()
```

```
def edit(request, name):
    initial_data = {
        'title' : name.capitalize(),
        'content' : util.get_entry(name)
    }

    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditForm(request.POST, initial=initial_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            content = form.cleaned_data['content']
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('wiki:index'))

    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        "name" : name.capitalize(),
        "content" : util.get_entry(name),
        "form" : NewTaskForm()
    })
```

I'm trying to show the name and the content of a markdown archive to edit that same file, the entire app is working fine (import and saving the file).

The server doesn't show any error messages and the page loads with no problems.
(If somenthing is wrong if the question i apologize, my english isn't one of the best)

Comment: Do you want to give the initial values to the NewTaskForm? If so, then add it there: ```"form" : NewTaskForm(initial = initial_data)```. Further, it is also not clear to me why you have two different forms in your view: EditForm and NewTaskForm. Are these the same?

Comment: I didn't realize i was refering the wrong form hahaha, but now it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use NewTaskForm() and not EditForm() i.e

```
"form" : NewTaskForm(initial = initial_data)
```

The EditForm you used has no relationship here.